# Swift - Push Segue

Tags: xcode, swift, segue

I have a setup like this:

[image: Screenshot]

All the segues are sit to `Push`, right now if i move from `SignupView` to `LoginView` it seems like it duplicates the `LoginView`, because the back button takes me to `LoginView` again, and then the `SignupView`, and when i try to add a segue from `LoginView` to the `tableViewController` the app crashes.

How exactly should i implement this ?

PS: the segue to the LoginView, is coming from the Login Button in the SignUp view. And to the tableview is doing from the Login Button in the LoginView

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just set up a Storyboard to mimic your setup and when I move to Login view, the back button takes me right back to the SignUp view.  I would check the Connections inspector for each view and make sure nothing extra is in there.